# Stop scrapy when the proxy queue is end

Tags: middleware, scrapy

I have a ProxyMiddleware which returns the proxies no more than 3 times, after which the proxy can no longer be used.

Suppose I have 3 proxies and each of them is used 3 times. I may parsing 9 items

And there were 25 items in the queue of scrapy. When I ran out of the proxy, how do I clean up the queue? Or to force to stop a parcer?

```
class CityPolygonsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'city_polygons'
cities_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/privat-api/cities/?country_code__in=ru,ua,kz,by'

custom_settings = {
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
        'geonames.pipelines.CityPolygonPipeline': 300
    },
    'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
        'geonames.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100,
    },
}

def start_requests(self):
    yield Request(url=self.cities_url, callback=self.parse_next, dont_filter=True)

def parse_next(self, response):
    raw = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    if raw['next']:
        yield Request(url=raw['next'], callback=self.parse_next, dont_filter=True)

    for city in raw['results']:
        city_href = self.search_url + '?' + city['name']
        request = Request(
            url=city_href, callback=self.parse_cities, dont_filter=True)
        request.meta['city_id'] = city['id']
        yield request

def parse_cities(self, response):
    result = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())['data']
    if result.get('exactResult'):
            yield CityPolygonItem(** result.get('exactResult'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track count of proxy usage in your proxy middleware. I would go with a dict with the proxy host:port combination as key, and hit count as value. On every proxy assignment check every entry in the dict. If there are no proxies with hit count less then 3, raise CloseSpider exception.

Here is the relevant part of the docs:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html?highlight=CloseSpider

Comment: Is it support for DownloaderMiddleware?

Comment: Yes, you can raise CloseSpider in DownloaderMiddleware

Comment: Is current active task (who has active proxy) end before scrapy is close?

Comment: Before closing the spider, Scrapy engine will process all scheduled requests and items in pipelines.